# How to test a project with multiple python versions in a sequential way?

Tags: python, unit-testing, travis-ci, sequential, noaa

I am developing a python adapter to interact with a 3rd party website, without any json or xml api (http://www.class.noaa.gov/).

I have a problem when Travis CI run multiple python tests (of the The Travis CI Build Matrix) concurrently.

The project is on GitHub at ecolell/noaaclass and the .travis.yml file is:

```
language: python
python:
  - "2.6"
  - "2.7"
  - "3.2"
  - "3.3"
install:
  - "make deploy"
script: "make test-coverage-travis-ci" #nosetests
after_success:
  - "make test-coveralls"
```

Specifically, I have a problem when at least 2 python versions were running their unit tests at the same time, because they use the same account of a website.

Is there any option to specify to The Build Matrix the execution of each python version in a secuential way?

Or maybe, Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't speak to how I would address the Travis CI problem but I would probably recommend [using tox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox) for testing the package on multiple Python versions.

Comment: Thanks! I also asked [here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2695) but your answer is good alternative.